# Limiting Bucket Size Returned By Aggregation

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a huge amount of elasticsearch data, I neeed to make aggregations and return buckets. I need to limit data size returned from elasticsearch to only get a sample for the data not all data.

I have tried adding "size" attribute. But it's not acceptable in bucketing aggregations.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "my_agg_1": {
      "histogram": {
        "field": "coAt",
        "interval": 86400,
        "offset": 1558216800,
        "order": {
          "_key": "asc"
        },
        "keyed": false,
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "my_agg_2": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "atr1",
            "missing": "NaN",
            "value_type": "string",
            "size": 2147483647,
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
            "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
            "order": [
              {
                "_count": "desc"
              },
              {
                "_key": "asc"
              }
            ]
          },
          "aggregations": {
            "atr2": {
              "top_hits": {
                "from": 0,
                "size": 1,
                "version": false,
                "explain": false,
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "coAt": {
                      "order": "desc"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "clientIP_count": {
              "value_count": {
                "field": "clientIP"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```